# Why is this being optimized away by g++? At least, I think that's what's going on

Tags: c++

When I run the following code

```
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char *argv []) {
  
  std::string simpleString("this is just a simple string");
  
  std::cout << "simpleString = " << simpleString << std::endl << std::endl;
 
  std::string one = (simpleString + ", one");

  const char * oneCharStar = one.c_str();
  std::cout << "simpleString + one: '" << oneCharStar << "'" << std::endl;

  const char * twoCharStar = (simpleString + ", two").c_str();
  std::cout << "simpleString + two: '" << twoCharStar << "'" << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

on my Fedora Core 23 machine, on which uname -a reports:

> "Linux glorp 4.5.7-202.fc23.x86_64 #1 SMP
> Tue Jun 28 18:22:51 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux"

and g++ --version says

> "g++ (GCC) 5.3.1 20160406 (Red Hat 5.3.1-6)"

the first output reads "this is just a simple string, one", while the second output shows the empty string.

I guess there's some kind of optimization going on here, but, on my previous Ubuntu machine (16.mumble, rest in peace), this code ran as I would have expected.  I just found that when I recompiled my application (using the same make files, etc) on the new machine, this code failed as above.

In addition, it works as I'd expect on the following platform as well:

> $ uname -a Linux t4240rdb
>
> 3.12.37-rt51+g43cecda #2 SMP Fri Mar 4 18:18:03 EST 2016 ppc64 GNU/Linux
>
> $ g++ --version
>
> g++ (GCC) 4.9.2
>
> Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

What's going on here?  Thanks!

Comment: You have undefined behavior.

Comment: I tried searching for an answer before posing the question.

Comment: @nzc Yes. Your question is well asked. However, when someone is more familiar with the exact problem, they may be able to come up with a better search and find your answer. That doesn't mean that your question is bad. Duplicates on StackOverflow are just fine.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that.

Comment: "Why is an expression such as (<makes-a-string>).c_str() ever useful then?"  Possibly the most important use of std::string::c_str() is to invoke Linux or POSIX API's or predecessor functions of a larger app that require a c-style null terminated string for input.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> ```
> const char * twoCharStar = (simpleString + ", two").c_str();
> ```

After this line, the temporary string `(simpleString + ", two")` is destroyed.

`std::string` allocates memory, and `c_str()` returns a pointer to that memory. In `std::string`'s destructor, the memory is deallocated. Thus, after this line, `twoCharStar` points to deleted memory.

Using memory after it is freed is undefined behavior.

Comment: Aha. That's it.  But...  Why is an expression such as (<makes-a-string>).c_str() ever useful then?  This seems like a bad affordance in the language.

Comment: It is useful *within the full expression*, but not *after* it. For example, `std::cout << (<makes-a-string>).c_str() << std::endl` is perfectly valid, since the temporary continues to live till the end of the full expression.

Comment: @nzc That's a good point. It wouldn't seem to be a bad idea to change `std::string` so that `c_str()` couldn't be called on an object that was about to go out of scope. However, it would break code (if I understand correctly). `someFunctionThatPrintsACString((simpleString + ", two").c_str())` wouldn't be undefined behavior because the temporary lives until after the function call, but if you changed `c_str()` to not work in that case, code like that would fail to compile

Comment: Yeah, I don't think it can be done away with -- I discovered that if one uses the expression immediately one gets the expected result.  But it seems very sketchy -- how would anyone know this is a bad idea aside from being aware of the intricacies of the language.  If we have to be aware of details like this, what good is abstraction?

Comment: @nzc The good news is that once you learn these patterns, they apply all over the place in C++. Having to think about things like this is part of what makes C++ harder than languages like Java or Python. But being able to do things like this is part of what makes C++ powerful. Abstraction at least helps you by making it so that there are fewer things to think about, even if you have to pay attention to details such as this. Some people have been trying to develop languages or libraries to solve these issues, but it's not an easy task

Comment: Sorry for whinging on there.

Comment: "Why is an expression such as (<makes-a-string>).c_str() ever useful then?"  non-sequitor.  You did not "<makes-a-string>", you did "<makes-a-char*>".

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN `(someString + "some literal")` creates a `std::string`, as `std::string` has an `operator+` taking a `const char *`

Comment: @nzc Arguably you already broke the abstraction by using c_str().  After all, that entire code block could be written with no `char *` in sight.  If all of those `char *` were replaced by `std::string`, the problem wouldn't occur.

Comment: Possibly the most important use of std::string::c_str() is to invoke Linux or POSIX API's or older functions that require a c-style null terminated string.

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN which, in fact, is what the original code was doing.